# NodeJS: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Ido\Desktop\SemestrialNodeJS\public\login.html'

Tags: node.js, express, filesystems, static-files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSwUq.png)I'm working on a NodeJS project, and I'm experiencing an error when trying to access the login page.

When I attempt to navigate to /login, I get the following error message:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Ido\Desktop\SemestrialNodeJS\public\login.html'

In the browser console, I also see this message:
login:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I'm not sure what's causing this issue. I checked the path and it appears correct. The login.html file is located in the public directory of my project, and I'm serving my static files using express.static('public').

I tried to implement user authentication by serving a login page (login.html) located in the 'public' directory. I'm using express.static('public') middleware to serve static files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE1dF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your file structure, it looks like you're trying to access public/pages/login.html but are instead trying to access `public/login.html` which doesn't exist, hence the 404 error. Try correcting your code to access the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the login.html page resides in the 'pages' directory of the public folder. Please recheck the path once!

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'pages', 'login.html'));
});
```

Should do the job

Comment: thank you, it is working - now im trying to move to the register page and same error appear to me - register.html:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: the 404 error shows it's either an incorrect path, or the file itself doesn't exist. Just double-check the path you're providing for the page.